# Working with multiple forms at once in PHP

Tags: php, forms, submit

I need to make an application which dynamically generates some number of forms and processes them. The user should be able to deal with each form individually without resetting the entered values in the other forms.

What I have right now is a master form that uses JS to generate some number of forms. The forms are all the same (i.e. I iterate on include("myForm.php").

My problem is that every time I submit one form, the values in the other forms get reset. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a three-step process:

1. Ensure that each form element on the page has a unique name and ID.
2. Store submitted values in the user's session.
3. Use PHP to insert the previously-entered values into the form fields when a form is posted.

Answer (score 1):

Post the form with AJAX, this doesn't refresh the page so you won't lose the values entered in the other forms